# Can an Officer of a US Company bar you from using Sick Time?

Tags: united-states, utah, employee

Scenario:

A US company in Utah provides sick time (not required by law).

A lower management officer tells an employee that they cannot call in sick on any Wednesday.

Is this the discretion of the Manager or is it in a legal grey area?

Comment: It sounds to me like an internal matter of company policy, since the sick leave is not mandated by law.  If the manager is not following company policy, the remedy would lie with the manager's manager or with the human resources department.  In other words, it's the manager's discretion if company policy says so ... unless the sick leave is specified in the terms of a contact of employment.  But see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_and_Medical_Leave_Act_of_1993: for certain reasons they have to give you leave, but it doesn't have to be paid.

Comment: It is not completely clear what you are asking.  Are they insisting the employee come in when sick, or refusing to pay them if they cannot?

Comment: They are insisting that the employee work when sick. The position is telecommuting, so there is no danger to the fellow employees.